# How to create a PDF on the fly with javascript and the PDF data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an AJAX call which calls a secure PHP API call that generates PDF file data (on the fly, no actual file) and returns it. How can I use this PDF file data in javascript/jquery to create and download a PDF file to the user?

I've originally tried setting the ajax call's heads to that of a PDF, but obviously you can't download files via ajax.

Comment: Do you have access to the PHP API that creates the PDF to have it return it in Base64 encoding?

Comment: @user1628733 yes. It returns the PDF data in Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically download a file from ajax call you can do the following.  In my example I returned an object that contained the file name, mime type, and Base64 data but maybe this can give you an idea on how to do what you are looking for.

```
PostDTO('/ReportService.asmx/DownloadReport', dto, function (result) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                if (window.URL && window.Blob && ('download' in a) && window.atob) {
                    // Do it the HTML5 compliant way
                    var blob = base64ToBlob(result.FileDataBase64, result.MimeType);
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = result.Filename;
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }
            });

function base64ToBlob(base64, mimetype, slicesize) {
        if (!window.atob || !window.Uint8Array) {
            // The current browser doesn't have the atob function. Cannot continue
            return null;
        }
        mimetype = mimetype || '';
        slicesize = slicesize || 512;
        var bytechars = atob(base64);
        var bytearrays = [];
        for (var offset = 0; offset < bytechars.length; offset += slicesize) {
            var slice = bytechars.slice(offset, offset + slicesize);
            var bytenums = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                bytenums[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var bytearray = new Uint8Array(bytenums);
            bytearrays[bytearrays.length] = bytearray;
        }
        return new Blob(bytearrays, { type: mimetype });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download file from ajax.
I did it from an angular application.
The idea :

1. Get the file data and ask a response type "arrayBuffer"
2. Be sure the data response are not transformed by your framework (as it is with angular)
3. Create a blob : var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf');//check type
4. Create an url : var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
5. Open the url : window.open(url);

You can verify the blob generated via the console, the blob url is showed. That url must open your pdf.